# unknown layout specifier 'triangles'

Tags: opengl, geometry, glsl, shader

I just started testing around with geometry shaders a bit. I want to draw a triangle for every point. This is my shader:

```
#version 150

layout (points) in;
layout(triangles, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0.1, 0, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position + vec4(0, 0.1, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

This is the error message:

> error C3008: unknown layout specifier 'triangles'

It kind of works when replacing "triangles" with "points", but obviously it's drawing points instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard the only allowed primitive types for outputs are

- points
- line_strip
- triangle_strip

So what you want is

```
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;
```